# Can we use requirejs in an angular application to manage/modularize only a part of the application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have an existing angular web app which doesn't use require.js. I have to create a new business module in the existing application. Can I use require.js for the new module only? So that I don't have to touch the existing code?

The existing index.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...

<script src="http://cdn.gse.site/angular/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/angDashboardService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/angDashboardController.js"></script>
<--- More custom scripts here --->

</body>
</html>
```

I tried including require-main.js in the existing index.html file without removing any of the existing script tags.
The require-main.js looks like this :

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: 'js',
   paths:{
      'angular' : '...'
   },
   shim: {
       'angular': {export: 'angular' },
       'new-module': {
            deps: ['angular'],   export: 'new-module'
       }
  }
});


require(['new-module'], function(){});
```

I am getting the error as following:

```
Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '<body class="preload ng-scope" ng-app="angDashboard">'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we use requirejs in an angular application to manage/modularize only a part of the application?

Yes you can (but why...?). You will be hits by some serious headache if you are not ware of what are you doing

Anyways to able to do this you must be fully understand the concept of `angularJS` and `requireJS` .

```
<script src="http://cdn.gse.site/angular/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/angDashboardService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/angDashboardController.js"></script>
```

This mean you already had an angular app running. So you will not (should not) config or load angular anymore with `requireJS`

```js
require.config({
   baseUrl: 'js',
   paths:{
      'async-module' : '...'
   },

   // You won't use 'shim' with this structure
   // shim: {}

});
```

**`async-module.js`**

```js
// assuming somewhere you have did this
// var app = angular.module([...]);
//
// NOW you need to convert this 'app' to global variable. So you can use it it requirejs/define blocks
// window.app = angular.module([...]);

define(function(){
  window.app.controller('asyncCtrl', function($scope){
    // controller code goes here
  });
});
```

Then somewhere inside your app, when you want to load this `async-module`

```
requirejs(['async-module'], function(){
    console.log('asyncCtrl is loaded!');
});
```

### SUMARY >>

It is possible to do what you asked but it does not very effective. And will be like hell in code management.

- If this answer took you lesser than 5 mins to understand, you can give it a try.
- If it took you longer than 5 mins to understand. I am highly not recommending you to do this. Using requireJS with angularJS in common way (everything loaded by requireJS) is already complicated and tricky. And this use case even beyond that.